# Bootstrap modal with angular. Modal not closing with a specific data-ng-click function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to figure out why this particular Bootstrap confirmation modal is not working with my desired function.  It does appear to work with a basic function bringing up an alert window but when I put the function I want it, it executes the function (in this case deletes an image from File-stack and my db) but it hangs up the modal window to where the modal window closes but there is that grey overlay stuck and it makes the page no longer functional. The function that seems to be holding this up is in the first button in the `modal-footer`div towards the bottom. The close button works fine and again it works fine when I put a simple function in place of the `removeMoreImage()` function Here is the code for the Bootstrap modal:

```
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-modal-more"> <span class= "glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span> REMOVE IMAGE</button>

        <div id="confirm-modal-more" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">

            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Remove Image Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Are you sure you want to delete this image?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"  data-ng-click="removeMoreImage(picture.url, car)" data-dismiss="modal" >REMOVE</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">CANCEL</button>
            </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the function that is is executing causing the hangup:

```
var getIndexIfObjWithOwnAttr = function(array, attr, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].hasOwnProperty(attr) && array[i][attr] === value) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

$scope.removeMoreImage = function(image, data) {
    var index = getIndexIfObjWithOwnAttr(data.morePictures, 'url', image);
    data.morePictures.splice(index, 1);
    filepickerService.remove(image);
    console.log(image + " has been removed!");
}
```

Any insights or advice would be great. It seems like sync issue but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using some query to force the modal close and it seems to work nicely though it is not as elegant of a solution as I was hoping for but it seems to work. This is the code I added to the function that was hanging up the modal.

```
 $('#confirm-modal-more').modal('hide');
 $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
 $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can close the modal in the function and return a result to the parent controller:

```
$uibModalInstance.close('some result of modal');
$uibModalInstance.dismiss('some reason for discarding and closing');

$scope.removeMoreImage = function(image, data) {
    var index = getIndexIfObjWithOwnAttr(data.morePictures, 'url', image);
    data.morePictures.splice(index, 1);
    filepickerService.remove(image);
    console.log(image + " has been removed!");

    // close modal
    $uibModalInstance.close();
}
```

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal